# Need help extracting links from a TD in webpage

Tags: python-2.7, css-selectors, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new at Python and trying my hands at building some small web crawlers. I am trying to code this program in **Python 2.7** with **BeautifulSoup** that would extract all profile URLs from this page and the subsequent pages

```
http://www.bda-findadentist.org.uk/pagination.php?limit=50&page=1
```

Here I am trying to scrape all the URLs that are linked to the details page, such as this

```
http://www.bda-findadentist.org.uk/practice_details.php?practice_id=6034&no=61881
```

However, I am lost as to how to make my program recognize these URLs. They are not within a DIV class or ID, rather they are encapsulated within a TD bgcolor tag

```
<td bgcolor="E7F3F1"><a href="practice_details.php?practice_id=6034&amp;no=61881">View Details</a></td>
```

Please advise on how I can make my program identify these URLs and scrape them. I tried the following, but neither worked

```
for link in soup.select('td bgcolor=E7F3F1 a'):
for link in soup.select('td#bgcolor#E7F3F1 a'):
for link in soup.findAll('a[practice_id=*]'):
```

My full program is as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def bda_crawler(pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= pages:
        url = 'http://www.bda-findadentist.org.uk/pagination.php?limit=50&page=' + str(page)
        code = requests.get(url)
        text = code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
        for link in soup.findAll('a[practice_id=*]'):
             href = "http://www.bda-findadentist.org.uk" + link.get('href')
             print (href)
        page += 1

bda_crawler(2)
```

Please help

Many thanks

Comment: try `soup.select("td[bg=E7F3F1] a")`.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. Here is the updated code - http://pastebin.com/d72eqNCW

Comment: did you try soup.select("td[bgcolor='E7F3F1'] a") or soup.select("a[href^='practice_details']) if all your links href attribute starts with "practive_details" text

Comment: Tried both; neither worked. Codes pasted at http://pastebin.com/iPfvEFsD

Comment: Found something that the page - http://www.bda-findadentist.org.uk/pagination.php?limit=50&page=1 doesn't open independently, it shows 'Error querying the database', so maybe I need to make a search first to return that search results page and try this code.

Comment: ok. try this now please: `soup.find_all("href='practice_details.php?practice_id=6034&amp;no=61881'");`.

Comment: Can someone please help me with how I can make a search with a certain  ZIP code at this page (in the postcode box) - http://www.bda-findadentist.org.uk/ first before I run the above program?

Comment: Thanks for your help Tahir, but it didn't work either. Does the page http://www.bda-findadentist.org.uk/pagination.php?limit=50&page=1 open at your end with all the listings on it or does it show a database error?